# Mixed moment between a Brownian motion in absolute value and another Brownian motion

Tags: brownian-motion

I have this given problem, how can I calculate this mixed moment?

> $$E[|B(t)|* B(1-t)]$$

I know that the expected value of the Brownian motion is $0$, so this is a covariance, but the absolute value make me insecure on how calculate the result.

Answer (score 1):

$B$ has the same distribution as $-B$, so
$$J:=E[|B(t)|* B(1-t)]=  E[|-B(t)|* (-B(1-t))]=-J.$$
Therefore $J=0$.